# Is there an SQL statement that I can run in MySQL that returns the location of my database(s) on my server?

Tags: mysql

I did a bit of research online and it looks like I need to have a column (or something) in my database called "sys.master_files" but I don't know what that consists of or how to create it.

Comment: I don't know where MySQL stores it, but sys.master_files is a Microsoft SQL Server system table.  Some quick googling on my part make me think that "SELECT @@datadir; " will work for MySQL.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968287/how-to-find-the-mysql-data-directory-from-command-line-in-windows

Comment: `sys.master_files` is a SQL Server system view. Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: MySQL Wordbench

Answer (score 2):

Just run this Query:

```
select @@datadir
```

and the result field + "Your Database Name" is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

For [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/information-schema-system_variables-table/) (may not work in MySQL):

```
select global_value from information_schema.system_variables 
  where variable_name = 'datadir'
```

or maybe

```
select global_value from information_schema.system_variables 
  where variable_name = 'innodb_data_home_dir'
```

depending on what you mean by "location of your databases".

For MySQL (tested in 5.5) replace `system_variables` with `session_variables`.